# I need help with ibox,lightbox and links issues

Tags: html

I chose ibox lightbox for my site. it has been working fine but i need to open a link in the current lightbox but to close the current lightbox first and open the link in a new light box. any ideas???
Here's the link for ibox http://www.ibegin.com/labs/ibox

Comment: You might get more responses if you post some code showing what you've got so far.

Comment: havent got any tha's why i'm askin!!!

Answer (score 0):

I test id , and it works

in JS

var aaa = document.getElementById('test');
aaa.onclick = _pub.hide;

HTML

`<a href="http://google.com" id="test" >test</a>`

you need to put to tags 'a' event onclick = _pub.hide;